# SQL Query to go through list of records and insert missing

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this.

[image]

You can see that `RECORD_ID` is having multiple records but with different `REC_STRING.
REC_STRING = LMT3` is missed for `RECORD_ID = 2222`.

I want to identify distinct `RECORD_IDs` which is not having the `REC_STRING = LMT3`.
Once Identified I need to insert it to the missed `RECORD_ID`.

Ex .
The script should do below.

1. Identify the `record_id = 2222` is missing the `record_string = LMT3`
2. Then script should insert values 2222 and LMT3 to the table.

Please help if anyone has an efficient way.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test script will give you the rows that will be inserted

```
select distinct RECORD_ID, 'LMT3'  from table a where not exists (select 1 from table b where a.RECORD_ID = b.RECORD_ID  and b.REC_STRING = 'LMT3')
```

Insert script will insert them:

```
Insert into table(RECORD_ID, REC_STRING )
select distinct RECORD_ID, 'LMT3'  from table a where not exists (select 1 from table b where a.RECORD_ID = b.RECORD_ID  and b.REC_STRING = 'LMT3')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH 
rec_strings AS ( SELECT DISTINCT rec_string
                 FROM sourcetable ),
record_ids  AS ( SELECT DISTINCT record_id
                 FROM sourcetable )
INSERT INTO sourcetable (rec_string, record_ids)
SELECT rec_string, record_ids
FROM rec_strings, record_ids
MINUS
SELECT rec_string, record_ids
FROM sourcetable
```

Answer (score 0):

For finding the missing entries you'll need something like the below

```
select a.RECORD_ID, 'LMT3'
from your_table a
left join (select RECORD_ID from your_table a where REC_STRING = 'LMT3') b on a.RECORD_ID = b.RECORD_ID
where b.RECORD_ID is null
group by a.RECORD_ID;
```

For inserting into the table it will depend on whether it is repetitive or one-time

Answer (score 0):

I can't promise it's efficient, but you could identify all possible values for each field, cross join them, and then identify (and insert) the missing values:

```
insert into foo
with all_records as (
  select distinct record_id from foo
),
all_strings as (
  select distinct rec_string from foo
),
all_combo as (
  select record_id, rec_string
  from all_records, all_strings
)
select *
from all_combo a
where not exists (
  select null
  from foo f
  where
    a.record_id = f.record_id and
    a.rec_string = f.rec_string
)
```

If this approach yields values you do not want, you can always just add a "where" clause to limit the non-relevant values.

Answer (score 0):

Left join the cartesian product of the distinct values of the columns `RECORD_ID` and `REC_STRING` to the table and insert the non matching rows:

```
INSERT INTO tablename ("RECORD_ID", "REC_STRING")
SELECT c."RECORD_ID", c."REC_STRING" 
FROM (
    SELECT t1."RECORD_ID", t2."REC_STRING"
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT "RECORD_ID" FROM tablename) t1
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT "REC_STRING" FROM tablename) t2
) c LEFT JOIN tablename t
ON t."RECORD_ID" = c."RECORD_ID" AND t."REC_STRING" = c."REC_STRING" 
WHERE t."RECORD_ID" IS NULL
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=534d53af6736f15a8a8331c89e5d6232).
Results:

```
> RECORD_ID | REC_STRING
> --------: | :---------
>      1111 | LMT1      
>      1111 | LMT2      
>      1111 | LMT3      
>      2222 | LMT1      
>      2222 | LMT2      
>      2222 | LMT3
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. Great Help.

Answer (score 0):

Please below query with results , you can achieve this by using loop as well ..

```
With CTE AS
(SELECT record_id,'LMT1' from dbo.records
Where record_id not in (Select distinct record_id from dbo.records WHERE rec_string='LMT1')
Union All
SELECT record_id,'LMT2' from dbo.records
Where record_id not in (Select distinct record_id from dbo.records WHERE rec_string='LMT2')
Union All
SELECT record_id,'LMT3' from dbo.records
Where record_id not in (Select distinct record_id from dbo.records WHERE rec_string='LMT3'
 )
 Insert into your_table (record_id,rec_string)
 Select * FROM CTE
```

Results:: [Please check fiddle link as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IE7P3.png)

[image]